Are chess federations allowed to hold tournaments outside their areas to save hotel costs?
As an example, a week in a full board hotel in Spain with easy access to an airport that has cheap daily flights to many UK airports outside of peak holiday season is cheaper (including cost of flying) than practically any UK hotel.   (The flights are also often cheaper than getting a train between UK cities.)
But there don't seem to be UK/England chess tournaments held in such good value hotels.

Chess federations to save hotel costs? "LOL" doesn't even scratch it. (Sorry, the responsible German dude has filed appeal, so until final instance throws the book at him, he is decidedly NOT guilty as $$$$ - Google is your friend.)


Are chess federations allowed to hold tournaments outside their areas to save hotel costs?

No. Only the Spanish chess federation is allowed to register FIDE tournaments in Spain. A few years ago there was something approaching a diplomatic incident when the Argentinian federation tried to register a tournament in the Falklands.
However there is nothing to stop a British organiser from asking the Spanish chess federation to register a tournament in Spain. In fact a few years ago (pre-Covid) I believe Charlie Storey was looking to register and organise tournaments for British juniors in Mediterranean countries like Morocco, Tunisia and Turkey. Even cheaper. How far he got I'm not sure.

Does FIDE prevent this if the event is only rated with a national rating system?  (I question if FIDE rating is of any value for English players below 2200 standard.)

@IanRingrose In general, FIDE only cares about FIDE regulations. Some exception would be Olympic matters because FIDE is part of the International Olympic system.
